# How to switch timezone in iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRLgl.jpg]

Iterm2 doesn't show the exact time in GMT+8, it shows GMT+0.

How should I switch the default setting?

I tried `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` and got `Time Zone: Asia/Taipei` but couldn't change the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default Timezone of your Rails application in `config/application.rb` file.

Look for `config.time_zone` value in the file. Set it to your required timezone.

For e.g:

```
config.time_zone = 'Asia/Taipei'
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. 
I set `config.time_zone = 'Asia/Taipei'` in `config/application.rb` but when I created new migration that still shows UTC+0.

Comment: @Edi Rails stores datetime in UTC in database. You shouldn't be worried about that. If you print created_at time in your Rails application you will see datatime according to the time_zone you set in your applicaiton.rb